# Is it possible to store file locally out side of our app in iOS?

Tags: ios, local-storage, file-manager

I have got many image data that need to be downloaded for future use. Is there any way to store images of my app outside of my app so that my app's memory usage will be low ??

Comment: May I know the reason for down vote ??

Comment: Probably because it's a poor question shows no research effort. On topic; what makes you think that it will consume memory if you save them in your app's documents directory?

Comment: @Desdenova So you are saying storing 500 hd images in an app's local storage wont affect an app which is very simple information display in nature  ??

Comment: Of course it won't. It's technically same thing as storing in camera roll.

Comment: @Desdenova But really it is different !!! I am sorry u can't view the scenario in that way :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can save the images to the gallery:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, 
                               id completionTarget, 
                               SEL completionSelector, 
                               void *contextInfo);
```

The completion function should be as the following function signature:

```
- (void) image: (UIImage *) image 
         didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error 
         contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo;
```

Read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum) for more info...

Comment: Thanks for fast reply . Can we create separate album in the name of our app so that it will be easy to group & view in Photos app ??

Comment: Yes you can but I never tried it... Try to read about `ALAssetsLibrary` there is there a function to create new album. From iOS8, there is new `Photos Framework`, but I can say nothing about it...